# Redirection in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts, url-pattern

I am using Struts 2 in my web application.

Normally, the struts filter in my application looks for *.do in URL patterns.

Now there is an additional requirement; when the application types in

```
       http://appname:port/login.jsp
```

, the decision to whether or not display the login.jsp is based on business rules.

So I should Ideally filter this URL pattern and send it through a struts action (let's call it LoginDecideAction).

Step 1 is to add the URL pattern in the filter URL pattern in the web.xml. Now how do I say struts that this URL pattern '*login.jsp' maps to LoginDecideAction ?

I am new to Struts 2 . A help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to go about this; I'll expand a bit on James' answer first.

(Although S2.0 is pretty old now; here's the [current action tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action.html)).

Expose a `login.jsp` file (i.e., don't put it under `WEB-INF`) and use the `<s:action>` tag inside it to run the `LoginDecideAction`. Logic inside the action determines what happens next, although by using the `executeResult="true"` technique means that whatever happens will be in the `login.jsp` URL, unless it has JavaScript to set the window location.

IMO this is a little clunky (and I'm not a big fan of the `action` tag). I'd rather the JSP page did an immediate redirect to an action that either rendered the JSP page, or rendered a different JSP page if the business logic says it should.

You *could* conceivably do what you're saying and have S2 actually process the `.jsp` request by setting `jsp` as an extension using the `struts.action.extension` property (see the [default `struts.properties` file docs for details](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/strutsproperties.html). But then you'd need to create an action for it, and probably make sure that no other `.jsp` requests were handled by S2, etc. Probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your login.jsp  displayed, add `s:action` tag to call the Struts action which can take care of your business logic. To display the view, use `executeResult="true"`. For more information on s:action, refer to the link below:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action.html